# Dynamic Form based on Signed in User

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, form

I am a total noob in coding. Back in engineering school we had some coding classes and I was good at it but I never really focused on that. I know some python and c# and that is about it.

I have a site. I use Cpanel and used Joomla to build the site.

In this site, certain users have "player" access. These users, every week, need to select an option from a form, and this option they can never select again. The game lasts 17 weeks, and by week 17, all of them are left with only two options which are then automatically selected, given that they always selected an option in the previous weeks, else they have to choose 2 out of the "many" options they could have.

Currently, I am using visforms to create a form where I have a dropdown list and they can select the option for that week. My problem is that, I cannot make that list dynamic. Meaning that they are always presented with all the options no matter what week we are in and what options they have selected before. Also, it is the same list for all users, it does not eliminate the option that they have already selected in previous weeks.

What I want to do is stop using visforms and create a form myself. I think I can figure out how to create a drop-down list in html with all the options needed. What I do not know is the following:

Whatever the user selects in that drop-down list, store it in an SQL database that I have created in CPanel. And store it based on each user.
Make the drop-down lists user dependent. Meaning that the options shown are based on the user that is seeing them. Because if they have selected an option before, I do not want them to have that option available anymore. And it is different for every user, of course.
Please point me in the right direction to solve my problem. I will do my due diligence and most likely come back in a future date with some questions but also with some code.

Thank you.

Comment: Yoir question feels like the type of "requirements dump" that you would convey to a hired Joomla developer.  If you are going to do this yourself, please take all initial steps that you are capable of and show us exactly what you are not able to do.  This question is vulnerable to being closed as Needs More Focus.  Please take our [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have already wrote everything I have done myself. The webpage is already doing part of what I want it to do. Using visforms and integration with google sheets and triggers I was able to almost do it. My problem is that Visforms sends the same form out to each user and does not allow removing options from the created form based on previous selection. 

I am definitely not trying to dump requirements on you guys, just wanted to state the problem as clear as possible and ask for guidance as to what exactly I need to learn. I have been trying for months but no luck.

Comment: What I mean is, please [edit] your question to show the earliest part where you are stuck with refactoring your project.

Comment: You should be using a form builder for this kind of task if you don't have much coding experience. There are many commercial extensions that are capable of this, quite easily and allows for custom PHP / JS coding withing the form builder. I have used many f these in the past in order to create dynamic, custom forms. They also allow you to send email notifications etc. Will save you loads of time.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at the form builders come application builder extenstions like Chronoforms or Fabrik where you can build in a lot of programming to glue the forms you want together and can include tables to store the data retrieved or sent.

You also mention creating a database via cPanel which unless you have some reason for having it external to the Joomla instance I would suggest using either of the extension mentioned above, or something similar, and create your tables within the Joomla database. It will make accessing them much simpler to manage.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful. I will definitely look into Chronoforms and Fabrik and see if those are more suitable for my application if I can figure them out. 

The reason I am using cpanel is... because... I do not know why haha. I basically bought it from godaddy and I thought it was necessary to be able to build my webpage with Joomla. (See, this is how noob I am to this). In fact, just a couple of weeks ago I started questioning this and I am thinking I don't need it. I already paid for another year so that buys me some time to figure out cheaper ways to do it.

Comment: cPanel is a good product for managing your hosting account and in most cases you do need it to create the initial data base where you install Joomla. Your question suggested that you had created another data base in addition to the Joomla data base and put your custom data in there. If you use the phpMyAdmin option in cPanel you can see how one data base, contains lots of tables to hold the data.

Comment: I see. No, it is the same SQL database within CPanel. Thanks a lot for your answers.